# SSIS Task runs in never ending mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package which is running successfully from a long time. This week I encountered that package has stopped running and goes into loop. On 7th the execution error was about not able to load to file server.

I did troubleshooting and found that a task is running endless. These 9,777 rows are not transferred to destination. Its buffering and hangs here. Can anyone please help ?

[image]

Comment: Looks like blocking at either the source or destination.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft There were 30 tables before this task from same source and to same destination, it's just this table which is not loading data. It has been running successfully from last one year.

Comment: Two things to check: the first is whether there is a popup window elsewhere telling you that something has encountered an error that didn't catch focus. Usually a Script Task/Component is involved but depending on your package design, there might be a concurrent activity. You can also check the Progress tab or the Output window to see whether there is actionable information there. The other observation is as David indicates - run `sp_whoisactive` or an equivalent set of queries to identify what is impeding progress.

Comment: @billinkc : I tried running the package at night time and it ran successfully. Why would this one task go in loop at times. This task has 17 million rows and DefaultBufferSIze of 10485760 and Default Buffer Max Rows 10000. Should I increase it ?

Comment: Given what little we know about your needs, it is terribly hard to say whether those buffer sizes are appropriate. It *feels* like as David said from the jump, check for blocking on the source or more likely, the destination. By default, you have fast load selected in the destination which means SQL Server will take a table lock. It can't lock until no other process has their finger on the table. If it's a really busy table during the day but less so at night, that could be a plausible reason it works erratically